# Why exception break application pools?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have the web api app with this method

```
public class TestController
{
     public UserView Get()
     {
            var testThread = new Thread(() => { throw new Exception(); });
            testThread.Start();
            Thread.Join();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return null;
     }
}
```

When i request this method, my application pools breaks. I receive this window [image]

And broken an application pools.
[image]
When i have this method

```
        var task = new Task(() => { throw new Exception(); });
        task.Start();
```

everything is good. Why?

Answer (score 2):

That's just how ASP.NET works. If a thread has an unhandled exception that isn't tied to a request, then it will bring the application down. This is described on [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/). He mentioned a detail followup post explaining specifically why comes down, but I was unable to find the followup post.

Depending on what you need to do in another thread, you can use an alternative such as async code, [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636892(v=vs.110).aspx), or a [scheduler](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) that has been specifically designed to work around these limitations such as Hangfire, WebBackgrounder or Quartz.NET.

Answer (score 2):

I guess because `Task` does not `throw` exceptions it return it as a property of `Task` object. If you does not check `Task` result it even won't be thrown until application start shutdown sequence and then it will be thrown as `UnhandledException`. I guess in `Thread` is different